# List and Prompt a specific object entity in AutoLISP

Tags: autocad-plugin, autolisp

I'm struggling with this error I'm getting, I'm new to AutoLISP.

Error message: 
bad argument type: stringp (142 . 3000.0)

The only goal at the moment is to prompt a selected specific object entity.

My code is the following:

```
(defun c:getObjectLenght()
    (setq a (car (entsel "\nSelect a object: ")))
    (setq b (entget a))
    (setq c (assoc 142 b))
    (prompt (strcat "\nThe value of 142 is: " c))
(princ)
)
```

I have tried alot of different solutions and searched the web,but without the result I'm looking for. So I hope someone can point me ind the right direction.

Thx in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per I know uses of `assoc` function is to find key value in associative list, this is like dictionary search you need to give key to search specific value check more [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-46309786-DAF6-4C28-8448-599FBC8A4F6A-htm.html).
and after applying function assoc it's output is in **list format** see below example.

```
(assoc  8 (entget (car (entsel)) ))
```

After selecting entity output like 
`(8 . "0")` 
This is layer name of selected entity in your case name may be different


Check one More Example

```
(assoc  10 (entget (car (entsel)) ))
```

After selecting entity ouput is 
`(10 3.25 5.5 0.0)` 
The output value is insert co-ordinate of selected entity.

Note that `Strcat` function Join **only** string check more [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-4430B1BF-DBB5-49D1-98F9-711B480976A1-htm.html).

In your function at line no 5, you **try to Join String with list** that why error is occurs.

As you mention error, I think you need to join value `3000.0.`

for that you can change your function as below.

```
(defun c:getObjectLenght()
    (setq a (car (entsel "\nSelect a object: ")))
    (setq b (entget a))
    (setq c  (if (assoc 142 b)  (rtos (cdr (assoc 142 b)))  "Not Found" ) )
    ;Note that rtos function use to convert decimal value into sting.
    ; And if condition use in case entity not contain Key value 142 so to avoid error.
    (prompt (strcat "\nThe value of 142 is: " c))
(princ)
)
```

I never come across DXF code `assoc 142` I google for that but not found much.

Comment: Thanks for you solution and feedback. It works perfectly :) The DXF code is not a standard one, it comes from an extension called hsbCAD.

Comment: you welcome, It's great to hear that solution is works. you can replace `rtos` function with `vl-princ-to-string` as mention by CAD Developer. it's very helpful if data type is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

`strcat` expect strings but `(assoc 142 b)` returns list `(142 . 3000.0)`, so You need to convert list to string. depended on entity You select and type of value You should use `rtos`, `itoa` or `vl-princ-to-string`

I suppose what You need is:

```
(strcat "\nThe value of 142 is: " (vl-princ-to-string (cdr(assoc 42 b ) ) ))
```

Comment: `vl-princ-to-string` nice function. I Never come across it.